# jQuery Validation for State

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I'm having trouble getting jquery.validation.js to validate for a state. Here's the custom code I wrote:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("state", function(state, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || state.match(/^d{2}[A-Z]+$/);
}, "Please specify a valid state");
```

What needs changed? It looks okay to me. It needs to match for 2 uppercase letters. Also, how does this format work? It really doesn't make much sense to me, all the weird symbols to specify which characters can be used. Is there a guide to this somewhere?

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: The weird characters are just JavaScript Regular Expressions (Regex)

Comment: I'll take a look around and see if I can find a decent tutorial. Thanks. I wasn't sure what to search for since I didn't know what it was called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try using this for capitalized state codes:

```js
/^(A[LKSZRAEP]|C[AOT]|D[EC]|F[LM]|G[ANU]|HI|I[ADLN]|K[SY]|LA|M[ADEHINOPST]|N[CDEHJMVY]|O[HKR]|P[ARW]|RI|S[CD]|T[NX]|UT|V[AIT]|W[AIVY])$/
```

In your example:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("state", function (state, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || state.match(/^(A[LKSZRAEP]|C[AOT]|D[EC]|F[LM]|G[ANU]|HI|I[ADLN]|K[SY]|LA|M[ADEHINOPST]|N[CDEHJMVY]|O[HKR]|P[ARW]|RI|S[CD]|T[NX]|UT|V[AIT]|W[AIVY])$/);
}, "Please specify a valid state");
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that's better than what I was going for. Do you know how to do what I initially asked for, though? I'm have another custom thing I need to do which is very similar (limiting the number of characters).

Comment: 2 uppercase letters would be: `/^[A-Z]{2}$/`